# Now You See Me ... Trophy / Achievement

Tags: achievements, mini-ninjas

What is the best method to grind out this trophy? Can I kill a bunch of guys while under stealth and then restart at a checkpoint to repeat the process - or will I lose my kill count doing that?

Do the kills still count if you die?

**EDIT**: What move counts as a stealth kill? Just to be sure I'm not wasting my time. From the tutorial you're supposed to hold `L2` to stealth, get close and then hold `SQUARE` to attack? But sometimes he just swings and doesn't instant kill them, and the stealth is broken.

Comment: from my experience with other games and their killing achievments i would say yes to all of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Is From PS3Trophies.org

Theres a great grind on the Grand River Canal level once you get camouflage...

Go to that first bridge and hit camo. Sneak up with L2 and stand just to the left of the capitan. Holding L2 start mashing [] in the general direction of the little guys. 3-6 kills per bout. Let them kill you and respawn at the nearby checkpoint

Lather, rinse, repeat

Source: http://www.ps3trophies.org/game/mini-ninjas/trophy/9462-Now-You-See-Me----.html  (1st Comment)